# Capture Google Chrome websockets activity

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I need to capture websockets responses from server on some page opened in Google Chrome. I can see them from Developer Tools in Network->WS panel. Can I capture them with creating browser extension or injected script?

Comment: The short answer would be "you can't". Here is the list of [all available APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) and there is no websockets in it.

Comment: Stan, what about chrome.devtools.network? Isn't capture websockets?

Comment: Yes, but they do not provide API for Chrome extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything with Wireshark but that wouldn't would be without chrome.

> With the updated Chrome Dev Tools,  you can now see the WebSocket
>   traffic coming and going to and from your browser without using tools
>   like Wireshark

[Reference](http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/05/09/inspecting-websocket-traffic-with-chrome-developer-tools/)

Comment: I need to operate with response using javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following links to check websocket activity

chrome://net-internals/#events&q=type:SOCKET%20is:active
chrome://net-internals/
If you mean anything different,then specify I will try to help you.

Comment: Can I capture this activity with javascript? Thank you

Comment: I haven't tried this,but I think if you are trying to check all socket connections initiated in that browser from web-page which is loaded from your web-server,it won't allow to do this.